# C++ digest authentication with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, hash

I want to ask a question about c++ rest library. Here, I want to write a digest authentication with the c++ code. I am using Qt library.
In order to make a digest authentication, I need to get the nonce token from the header. I am trying to read the response header with my code . The code below works properly to get the response but "manager->head" is not working. Could you help me, how can I read the header, so I can get the nonce token.

```
QNetworkRequest request1;
request1.setUrl(QUrl("http://172.16.101.68/reset")); 
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply*reply = manager->get(request1);
//QNetworkReply*reply = manager->head(request1); this is not working
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

QByteArray data1 = reply->readAll();
QString dataReply(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem that way;
I have preferred to write the digest authentication in classical way. there are two steps in digest authentication. These are receiving the nonce and Sending username + password + nonce combination. Below code is the part of sending  password, username, nonce in c++ QnetworkAccessManager.

```
 digestResponse = "Digest username=\"" + _userName  + "\"" + ", realm=\"" + _realm + 
    "\"" + ", nonce=\"" + _nonce + "\""
                   + ", uri=\"" + urlAfterIp +"\"" + ", algorithm=MD5" + ", response=" 
  + "\"" + ha3  +"\"" + ", qop=" + _qop + ", nc="
                   + _ncString + ", cnonce=\"" +_cnonce + "\"";


    //setting the variables.............

  QEventLoop loop;

  QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
  QNetworkRequest networkRequest;
  networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("http://172.16.101.68/reset"));

  networkRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", digestResponse.c_str());
  QObject *a = new QObject();
  QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(networkRequest);

  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
          a, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
          a, SLOT(slotOnRequestCompleted()));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
          a, SLOT(slotOnRequestError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
          a, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));


  loop.exec();

  QByteArray dataReceived = reply->readAll();
  QString dataReply(dataReceived);
```